# How to set random data in brick-masonry layout in react native iOS application

Tags: ios, react-native

I am working on a react native application, where I have user "react-native-masonry-brick-list" library for brick view, data is arranged in brick view if user set size of articles in predefine manner, such as I have consider 4 view ratio, which are 100%, 75%, 50% and 25%.
if user pass 1st article 25%, and 2nd article 75%, than 3rd article 100% and son on, than list will be in proper manner.
whereas if user randomly set size than there will be some space left.

how to arrange data in such manner that there only remain space left in last block.

[example of predefine size in brick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHgzH.jpg)

[randomly set size for brick, there is space left in brick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hQmQ.jpg)

[randomly arrange data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXvYE.png)

Answer (score 0):

AS you have used react-native-masonry-brick-list library, it has no option of arranging random data in brick format, you can opt for two options,

1. fetch data on app than apply sorting over it or
2. by applying sorting at your backend

this will be a temporary fix